# How to assign a function to an JS Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I create a callable Object in JS.

1. Function - Working

```js
const a = () => 'a()';

a.b = 'a.b';

console.log(a.b); // 'a.b'
console.log(a()); // 'a()'
```

What if I create an Object first?

2. Object - Not working

```js
const a = {
  b: 'a.b',
}

Object.assign(a, () => 'a()');

console.log(a.b); // 'a.b'
console.log(a()); // Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function
```

Is there an alternative to Object.assign to get 2. working?